# Q: how to render css to head tag only If condition is true in haml

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, haml

I want to css to head tag in haml only if @ticket&.used? is true.

so I wrote below.

```
- content_for :layout_head do
  :css
    #info{ "#{'display:block' if @ticket&.used? }" }
```

I expected this output in head tag

```
<style>
  #info{ display:block; }
</style>
```

but actual is like this and css doesn't work well

```
<style>
  #info{ "display:block;" }
</style>
```

please any hint.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don‘t need the outer quotes, Haml will interpolate any `#{ ... }` in a filter.

So you can just use:

```haml
- content_for :layout_head do
  :css
    #info{ #{'display:block' if @ticket&.used? } }
```

Comment: It works well after I remove the outer quotes. Thanks!!